# For each controller in jmeter getting the last value only

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, jmeter

```
test plan
       --> Thread Group
               --> SOAP request --> Gets me the PID from the response with xpath xtractor
```

Now with this value extracted I have to use them in the next request and since there are multiple values in it, I am using `ForEach` Controller in the next request to loop through each of the `PID` recieved in the response to make a new request but here is the problem, it takes only the last value from the response and just ignores rest of the values and I need to run this for 3 times but it run only once and with last value

Comment: does anyone has any idea how to achieve this ,, I really need this solution badly today, I tried using the counter but no help

Comment: ok I just added the same request in the previous rest loop controller and it just seem to work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I just added the same request in the previous rest loop controller and it just seem to work fine – 
so basically its doing two things in the same loop controller
lloocontroller--> request1--> execute--> xpath extractor
              --> request2-->get value from xpathextractor--> execute